# How do I clone an entire GitHub repository (commits, issues, wiki, everything) to a GitHub organization

Tags: git, github

I was recently added to my company's GitHub organization. How would I go about basically duplicating a private repository on my personal GitHub account into the company GitHub? I'm trying to preserve all previous commits, issues, the wiki, etc.

Comment: Wiki and source code are easy to migrate (just add another remote and push). Regarding issues, I have no clue...

Comment: Do you have to clone it? Can you just transfer it? https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/

Comment: I would like to keep my copy as a private repo, but also transfer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this howto https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/01/totw-copying-a-full-git-repo/ it seems to be what you are looking for. This show you how you can move a full Git repository from one remote server to another.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: note that this solution doesnt help with keeping issues/releases/etc, only cloning the git repo